# Overriding active admin session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I need to add two factor authentication for active admin.
Whenever admin tries to login I need to verify them before giving access. Verification can be done either by sending OTP to email or mobile.
So I need to over ride the Sessions controller for active admin devise so that I can add the functionality to it.
I found a solution which said that we can do that inside initializers folder.
I over ride th create method and its working fine.

#config/initializers/active_admin_devise_sessions_controller.rb

```
 class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController
   include ::ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller
   def create

   if params[:admin_user].present? 
    email = params[:admin_user][:email]
    password = params[:admin_user][:password]
    admin_user = AdminUser.find_by_email(email)
    if admin_user.present? && admin_user.valid_password?(password)
    @admin_user = admin_user
    redirect_to verification_method_path
    end
   else
     flash[:error] = "No User Found"
     redirect_to :back
   end


  end

  def verification_method

  end

end
```

now my problem is I want to add few methods so I can render some views for verification process for login.
And I am not able to add any custom routes for active admin in session controller so I can call it and use as needed.

my active admin routes

```
  devise_for :admin_users,ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

my custom GET route to render second form for login verification

#active admin session controller verification routes

```
 get '/admin/verification_method' => 'active_admin/devise/sessions#verification_method', via: :get, as: "verification_method"
```

I didnt find anything similar to my problem.
Please guide me how can this be done.